# Discord JS calling JSON

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm currently working on a discord js bot which will fetch some information from a JSON file on a website. I have been able to get it to work with photos but I have no idea how to get the information I want from this JSON file. I'm sorry if this is really simple but I'm new to JS

The part I need from the JSON file is "name" and then I need it too print out all of the names that are in the file at the time.

This is currently a JSON file that I am testing with, it's a FiveM server player list.

http://145.239.206.148:30120/players.json

If you could please provide me with some information on how to get all of the player names that would be much appreciated.

This is the blank "Fivem" command file.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {


}
module.exports.help = {
    name: "fivem"
}
```

Comment: SO is not a site where we write code for you; edit your answer to ask for a specific problem or pay somebody to write your code

Comment: I'm not asking someone to write it for me... I'm asking for someone to provide me with information on to get it.. This could be resources or advice that I haven't come across.. I explained what the problem was, what I need and then I said "If you could please provide me with some INFORMATION on how to get all of the player names that would be much appreciated". If I wanted someone to write something for me I would of said "Can someone please write me this code"...

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the JSON file with [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and traverse over each of the returned Object's array elements to access the name attributes and values. A [JSON Parser](https://jsonformatter.org/json-parser) would be helpful to visualize the indices of it's structure. Resources : [JavaScript JSON Parsing](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/javascript-tutorial/javascript-json-parsing.php)

Answer (score 0):

I used an api so I think you could do something like:

```
https.get('http://145.239.206.148:30120/players.json', response => {
        response.setEncoding('utf8');
        let body = '';
        response.on('data', data => {
            body += data;
        });
        response.on('end', () => {
            body = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(body) // You obtain  your json as an js object...
        });
    });
```

It worked for me so...

MrNossiom